# How to segregate Elasticsearch index and search path as much as possible

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-5

I am planning to segregate Elasticsearch index and search requests as much as possible to avoid any unnecessary delay in the indexing process. There is no such a thing as an Elasticsearch dedicated search node or index node. However, I was wondering if the following scenario is suitable. As far as I understood, I cannot segregate search requests from index requests completely because at the end both hit ES data nodes, but it is what I think can help a little:

- Few Elasticsearch Coordinator nodes (No master/data) to deal with search requests and route them to the corresponding data node. Hence, for creating search client to deal with search requests, coordinator node URL will be used only.
- Use Elasticsearch data nodes directly for the index path and ignore coordinator nodes for indexing.

In this case, the receiving data node will act as a coordinator node for indexing path and dedicated coordinator nodes will be used to route to a replica on data nodes. Data node unnecessary load due to search routing can be minimised.

I was wondering if there is another way to provide segregation at a higher level or I am insane to not use coordinator nodes for the indexing path as well.

P.S: My use case is heavy indexing and light/medium search

Answer (score 1):

You cant separate indexing and search operations, indexing will write on the primary shard, then on the replica shard, whereas search can be done only on primary shards.

If you care about write performance:

- no replica
- refresh_interval > 30s, keep analyzer simple
- lot of shards (across data nodes)
- send insert/update queries on data nodes directly
- try to have a hot/cold data architecture (hot/cold indices)

Coordinator nodes can not improve search performance at all, this depends on your workload (aggs etc...).

As usually, all tuning stuff depend on your data and usage, you must find the good balance between indexation and searching performance, use the `_node/stats` endpoint to see whats going on.

Comment: So are you saying that there won't be any benefit of using dedicated coordinator nodes? Even from the fact that date nodes won't be used as coordinator nodes and most of the resources can be dedicated to index/search requests. What if we want to analyze it from the cache perspective. Is there any specific type of cache that can be hit on the coordinator nodes without routing to data nodes?

Comment: BTW, I read somewhere that search can be done on any replica. It can be done even on an in-sync replica.

Comment: Your data is on data nodes, most the search work is Lucene, so coo. nodes could not improve performance.  You must test and measure your own workload. Any read operation will prefer replica shards, yes.